# an inequality for completely positive maps

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C$*-algebras and $\phi:A\to B$ a completely positive contractive map. I want to show that, for any $a,b\in A$;
$$\Vert \phi(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b)\Vert\leq\Vert\phi(aa^*)-\phi(a)\phi(a^*)\Vert^\frac{1}{2}\Vert b\Vert.$$

After reading some solutions for inequalities related to completely positive maps, it seems [Stinespring's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinespring_dilation_theorem) and the $2$-positive trick are good starting points but I don't know how to proceed. A related post containing the mentioned ideas is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823878/proving-two-stubborn-inequalities-for-completely-positive-maps-in-c-algebras). Indeed, $\phi(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b)$ is very similar to the determinant of a martix, for example, $
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi(ab) & \phi(a)  \\
\phi(b) & I  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$X=\begin{bmatrix} a^*&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Because $\phi$ is ccp (though $2$-positive and contractive is enough),
$$
\phi^{(2)}(X)^*\phi^{(2)}(X)\leq\phi^{(2)}(X^*X).
$$
This gives us
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi(aa^*)-\phi(a)\phi(a)^*&\phi(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b)\\ [\phi(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b)]^*&\phi(b^*b)-\phi(b)^*\phi(b)
\end{bmatrix}\geq0.
$$
It is not hard to show that a matrix $\begin{bmatrix} r&s\\ s^* &t\end{bmatrix} $ is positive if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a contraction $x_\varepsilon$ such that $s=(r+\varepsilon)^{1/2}x_\varepsilon (t+\varepsilon)^{1/2}$.  Thus
$$
\|\phi(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b)\|\leq\|\varepsilon+\phi(aa^*)-\phi(a)\phi(a)^*\|^{1/2}\,\|\varepsilon+\phi(b^*b)-\phi(b)^*\phi(b)\|^{1/2}.
$$
Since $\phi(b^*b)-\phi(b)^*\phi(b)\geq0$ and $\phi(b^*)\phi(b)\geq0$, we have
$$
\|\phi(b^*b)-\phi(b)^*\phi(b)\|\leq\|\phi(b^*b)\|\leq\|b\|^2.
$$
This, together with letting $\varepsilon\to0$, gives us
$$
\|\phi(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b)\|\leq\|\phi(aa^*)-\phi(a)\phi(a)^*\|^{1/2}\,\|b\|
$$

Comment: Useful, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

As the OP suggested, this can also be showed using the Stinespring dilation when $A$ is unital. For the sake of completeness for future readers, I add an answer with such a solution. Choosing a faithful representation of $B$, we may regard $\phi$ as a map $\phi \colon A \to B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$. By Stinespring's theorem, there exists a Hilbert space $K$ with a representation $\pi \colon A \to B(K)$ and an operator $V \colon H \to K$ such that $$\phi(a) = V^* \pi(a) V \quad (a \in A).$$
Since $\phi$ is contractive, so is $V$. It follows that $I - VV^*$ is positive and contractive. Hence, we have
\begin{align}
\lVert \phi(ab) - \phi(a) \phi(b) \rVert &= \lVert V^* \pi(a) (I - VV^*)^{1/2} (I - VV^*)^{1/2}  \pi(b) V \rVert \\
& \leq \lVert V^* \pi(a) (I-VV^*)^{1/2} \rVert \lVert (I-VV^*)^{1/2} \pi(b) V \rVert  \\
& \leq \lVert (I-VV^*)^{1/2} \pi(a^*) V \rVert\lVert b \rVert \\
&= \lVert ((I-VV^*)^{1/2} \pi(a^*) V)^* (I-VV^*)^{1/2} \pi(a^*) V \rVert^{1/2} \lVert b \rVert \\
&= \lVert V^* \pi(a) (I - VV^*) \pi(a^*) V \rVert^{1/2} \lVert b \rVert \\
&= \lVert \phi(aa^*) - \phi(a) \phi(a^*) \rVert^{1/2} \lVert b \rVert 
\end{align}

The non-unital case can be deduced from the unital case since completely positive contractive maps extend to maps of the same type on the unitization (e.g. by Arveson's Extension Theorem).